# On what thread are electron menu callbacks executed?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, typescript, callback, electron

I'm struggling to understand electron menu items and where their callbacks gets executed.

1. I define a menu item **A** in *main* and add a callback to it
2. I then access that menuitem using **global** in a *renderer* process
3. Next I add a new item **B** to the menu with a callback in the *renderer* process
4. Finally in the *render* process I use **remote.Menu.setApplicationMenu()** with **both**

To my surprise, **A's callback executes in main**, but **B's runs in the window** of the renderer process.

This is exactly how I want it. But is it safe? Since *remote* is a wrapper for IPC calls to main process, I don't understand how these callbacks get allocated to the correct thread?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a entry in the documentation that I missed on this: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote#passing-callbacks-to-the-main-process

It appears to answer the question (: